# Widgets + Static Block issue

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, widgets, cms-block

I am struggling with an issue since yesterday, i really need some help from someone who is more experienced with magento.  I have a problem with the Widgets/static blocks. Whenever i create a static block, and attach it to the widget, it wont show up in my store. I triple checked the settings, i also followed the provided guide that came with my theme, but still no success.

This is what i do:

1. First i created a static block with some lorem text.
2. Then i created a widget and attached the static block with the lorem text.
3. Then i select Display on: all products
4. Products: specific product page
5. Then i the select the specific page i want the static block to show on
6. Then i select the block reference (Product view secondary column container 1, my theme guide told me to use this)

But it's still not showing up:(

1. I already tried flushing the cache
2. i double checked my "Design Package" setting of the widget which is ultimo/default
3. Deleted cookies
4. Tried setting Anchor to Yes/NO

I'm using this theme: http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798

I have absolutely no idea what i'm doing wrong, can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance: